# FullAjaxExceptionHandler not redirecting to custom error page (URL stays same)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, error-handling, omnifaces

In my application the user should be redirected to a custom error-page when a specific exeption is thrown.

The error-page is shown but the URL doesnt change to the error-page location.

Following are the relevant code snipplets

inside my web.xml I have the following declarations.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>de.mmo.base.util.login.NoSidException</exception-type>
    <location>/error/NoActiveSID.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>de.mmo.exceptions.NotLoggedInException</exception-type>
    <location>/error/NotLoggedInExc.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/error404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/error500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

In my faces-config.xml I tried the following two declarations

```
<factory>                                                             
    <exception-handler-factory>                                       
        org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory
    </exception-handler-factory>                                  
</factory>
```

and

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>
        de.mmo.test.MyExceptionHandlerFactory
    </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

When I tried with MyExceptionHandler I commented the FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory out.

Following is the MyExceptionHandler code

```
public class MyExceptionHandlerFactory extends ExceptionHandlerFactory {

    private ExceptionHandlerFactory parent;

    public MyExceptionHandlerFactory(ExceptionHandlerFactory parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
        ExceptionHandler result = parent.getExceptionHandler();
        result = new MyExceptionHandler(result);

        return result;
    }

}        

public class MyExceptionHandler extends FullAjaxExceptionHandler {


    private ExceptionHandler wrapped;

    public MyExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getWrapped() {
        return this.wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    protected String findErrorPageLocation(FacesContext context,
        Throwable exception) {
        System.out.println("inside my findErrorPageLocation");
        if(exception instanceof NoSidException) {
            System.out.println("inside exception instanceof NoSidExceptin");
            return "/error/NoActiveSID.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {
        return super.findErrorPageLocation(context, exception);
    }
}
```

And last I have e.g. the NoSidExceptino class

```
public class NoSidException extends FacesException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2350480134523249331L;
    public NoSidException(){
        super ("ACHTUNG: SID ist abgelaufen !");
    }
}
```

The error pages are all in
webapp --> error --> *.xhtml files

My application is running on a glassfish server.

If you need more informations I will tell them :)

thx for help

----------EDIT---------------------------------------------------------------

I was able to solve my problem with javascript.

In the header of the error-page i insert

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).load(function() {
    redirectToErrorPage (); 
    });            
</script>
```

And in the body I have a remoteCommand

```
<h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand name="redirectToErrorPage" action="#{nav.baueNavPfad(pfadKonst.ERROR_NOSID, false)}">
    </p:remoteCommand>
</h:form>
```

Comment: It is not redirecting when you cause the exception through "classic" navigation or when using Ajax calls?

Comment: Hi SJuan76, the exception is thrown through ajax calls. For this I used the org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory

Comment: For additional information: in my web.xml I have the following declaration
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Production</param-value>
 </context-param>